# how to get text from first and second line title in the button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

How I can get text from the first and second lines in the button? And how I can get how many lines are used in the button title?

I create a button:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(15, 30, 150, 30)
button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping;
```

And then I want to get how many lines the button uses to display the title. And I want to get the text of the first line of the button's title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some calculation you can get the number of the lines of your `UIButton` title and get the first line string.
I wanted to create some extension to make the code "most portable"

**Starting with your code**:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
let title = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, legimus tacimates eam in. Inani petentium iudicabit nam ut, verear nostrud in sea. Everti repudiare comprehensam et has"
button.frame = CGRectMake(15, 150, 150, 30)
button.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

[image]

So, first **add these extensions**:

```
extension UIFont {
    func sizeOfString(string:String) -> CGSize {
        return (string as NSString).sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:self])
    }
    func sizeOfStringConstrained(string: String, constrainedToWidth width: Double) -> CGSize {
        return NSString(string: string).boundingRectWithSize(CGSize(width: width, height: DBL_MAX),
                                                             options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                             attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: self],
                                                             context: nil).size
    }
}

extension UIButton {
    func getLinesArrayOfString() -> [String] {

        let text:NSString = (self.titleLabel?.text)!
        let font:UIFont =  self.titleLabel!.font
        let rect:CGRect = self.frame

        let myFont:CTFontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(font.fontName, font.pointSize, nil)
        let attStr:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text as String)
        attStr.addAttribute(String(kCTFontAttributeName), value:myFont, range: NSMakeRange(0, attStr.length))
        let frameSetter:CTFramesetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attStr as CFAttributedStringRef)
        let path:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathAddRect(path, nil, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, 100000))
        let frame:CTFrameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, nil)
        let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame) as NSArray
        var linesArray = [String]()

        for line in lines {
            let lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line as! CTLine)
            let range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(lineRange.location, lineRange.length)
            let lineString = text.substringWithRange(range)
            linesArray.append(lineString as String)
        }
        return linesArray
    }
}
```

Then, **write this code to get your results**:

```
let font = button.titleLabel?.font
let sizeString = font?.sizeOfString(title)
let sizeStringConstrained = font?.sizeOfStringConstrained(title, constrainedToWidth: Double(button.frame.width))
let division = (sizeStringConstrained?.height)!/(sizeString?.height)!
let numLines = Int(ceil(division))
print("Number of lines used in my button title: \(numLines)")

let array = button.getLinesArrayOfString()
print("The first line of my button title is: \(array.first)")
```

[image]